# How to add orcid link to given ieee access latex code template?

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates, code, links, ieeeaccess

https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/LaTeX.zip

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author,
Jr}.\authorrefmark{3},
\IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}
\address[1]{National Institute of Standards and 
Technology, Boulder, CO 80305 USA (e-mail: author@boulder.nist.gov)}
\address[2]{Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins, 
CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu)}
\address[3]{Electrical Engineering Department, University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 
80309 USA}
\tfootnote{This paragraph of the first footnote will contain support 
information, including sponsor and financial support acknowledgment. For 
example, ``This work was supported in part by the U.S. Department of 
Commerce under Grant BS123456.''}

\markboth
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}
{Author \headeretal: Preparation of Papers for IEEE TRANSACTIONS and JOURNALS}

\corresp{Corresponding author: First A. Author (e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov).}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newsavebox{\ORCIDlogo}
\savebox{\ORCIDlogo}{%
\setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr 1em/256\relax}%
\begin{picture}(256,256)%
  \color[HTML]{A6CE39}\put(128,128){\circle*{256}}%
  \color{white}%
  \put(78.6,199.2){\circle*{20}}%
  \moveto(70.9,176,9)\lineto(86.3,176,9)\lineto(86.3,69.8)\lineto(70.9,69.8)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
  \moveto(108.9,176.9)\lineto(150.5,176.9)%
  \curveto(190.1,176.9)(207.5,148.6)(207.5 ,123.3)%
  \curveto(207.5,95,8)(186,69.7)(150.7,69.7)%
  \lineto(108.9,69.7)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
  \color[HTML]{A6CE39}%
  \moveto(124.3,83.6)\lineto(148.8,83.6)%
  \curveto(183.7,83.6)(191.7,110.1)(191.7,123.3)%
  \curveto(191.7,144.8)(178,163)(148,163)%
  \lineto(124.3,163)%
  \closepath\fillpath%
\end{picture}%
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\ORCIDlogo}}}

\usepackage{hyperref} %<--- Load after everything else

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\author{John Doe \orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Know that you can enclose your code as ``` code ```. This way it will have the proper format

Answer (score 0):

The `orcidlinks` package can do exactly this for you (https://ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink?lang=en)

```
\usepackage{orcidlink}
```

You can than simply put

```
John Doe\orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0000}
```

Maybe you need some additional formatting than to stick to the template.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref} %Used so orcidlink does not lead to bookmark creation
\hypersetup{hidelinks} %Used so no box around orcidlinks
```